# ¿Cómo obtener la diferencia en horas de dos fechas en javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, date, javascript-objeto, nestjs

Cordial Saludo.
He tenido un problema con proceso desde hace dos semanas.
Tengo un objeto (entidad) que tiene dos campos que son fechas.

Lo que necesito hacer es sacar la diferencia en horas entre las dos fechas. He estado investigando y todos los ejemplos que encuentro utilizan el `new Date()` para sacar la fecha , no toman una fecha ya existente.

Esta sería la entidad `@Entity({name:'Tiket'})`

```
export class Tiket
{

@Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', nullable: false })
fechaHoraIngreso: Date;

@Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', nullable: false })
fechaHoraConsultaPago: Date;

@Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', nullable: false })
fechaHoraSalida: Date;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si usas `timestamp` solo debes usar matemáticas básicas, te pongo un ejemplo:

1627495182-1627487982=7200 -> 7200/60/60=2h

Todas los `timestamp` parten desde el mismo punto, así que para saber la diferencia que se llevan solo tienes que restarlos y te devolverán la diferencia en segundos, después según que datos te interesen divides entre 60 y obtendrás minutos, otra vez por 60 y te dará horas, otra vez por 24 y tendrás días, etc...
(El resultado de la resta te puede dar un numero negativo, pásalo por `abs()` antes de meterlo en las divisiones, pero luego te tienes que acordar y depende de para que lo uses indicar que dio negativo)

`timestamp` Es uno de los formatos de fechas mas simples de trabajar y mas rápidos en cuanto a procesamiento, por eso lo recomiendo allá donde puedo.